# media-libs/libogg package won't install because lack of certificate

Tags: kde, compiling, gentoo, emerge

[Intro/Context - https://ibb.co/8jkBNLy.](https://ibb.co/8jkBNLy)

What I am trying to do: I want to install kde-plasma desktop enviroment, on my gentoo machine that works only in text mode now. `emerge --ask kde-plasma/plasma-meta` won't work, because of libogg package, so I tried to install only this package: `emerge --ask media-libs/libogg` and then I saw there was a problem with emerge command, that uses wget and wget cannot download media with broken secutiry certificate by default, so I needed to create `/etc/make.conf` with following contents:

```
GENTOO MACHINE / # cat /etc/make.conf 
RESUMECOMMAND="/usr/bin/wget -c --no-check-cddertificate \${URI} -P \${DISTFILES}/\${FILE}" 
FETCHCOMMAND="/usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate \${URI} -P \${DISTFILES}/\${FILE}"
```

After that `emerge --ask media-libs/libogg` produces [this output](https://pastebin.com/uAUFLtGy), but still doesn't install.

I also tried downloading and installing .tar.xz of libogg myself, but it didn't work as well. I did:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

And sure, it created lib directory with some files, but when I tried `emerge --ask kde-plasma/plasma-meta` again, and it was still trying to download `libogg` anyways.

I would appreciate if you could help me with setting up my KDE Plasma desktop enviroment in any way, if you need anymore info check [Intro/Context](https://ibb.co/8jkBNLy), or ask me some questions.

Comment: This won't necessary solve your problem however, for sure, you should not have created /etc/make.conf this seems to be confusing portage since you already get portage's make.conf located in /etc/portage/make.conf. You should first remove /etc/make.conf then eventually add your fiddlings to /etc/portage/make.conf

Comment: Then please post /etc/portage/repos.conf/gentoo.conf (we need to first fix portage's troubles)

Comment: Additionally make sure that the user issuing the emerge command gets write access rights to the distfiles directory (normally /var/cache/distfiles) which should be rwx for root and portage group. => either you emerged as root or your user is member of the group portage.

Comment: Sure, will try this and let you know.

Comment: Well, I already figured this out, I am posting an answer. Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I already figured this out thanks to [gentoo forums thread](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1146531.html%20I%20needed%20to). What I needed to do is to re-install `app-misc/ca-certificates`. Also guys from comments were right about my misunderstanding of file locations - I removed wrong `/etc/make.conf` file.